# How to send a random color hex from flask backend to html

Tags: flask

I want to send a random hex to my front-end from back-end any ideas how to do it??

for example

```
return render_template("random.html", color=#random color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will do it**

```
import random

    def color():
        color = "#{:06x}".format(random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))
        return color

return render_template("random.html", color=color())
```